# Change ReSharper's color scheme

Tags: resharper, color-scheme

Does anyone know how to change the ReSharper color scheme in VS2008 SP1?

I've looked around and all the posts out there on the internet pointed to dead-ends.
JetBrains at one point told users to change the colors inside VS (Tools | Options | Fonts and Colors | Text Editor) but I don't see any ReSharper items in there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In VS|Tools|Options|Environment|Fonts and Colors, ensure the "Show settings for:" listbox is set to Text Editor and you will find the ReSharper items.

Comment: I suggest reinstalling Resharper.  I have broke my install a couple of times and found things missing that weren't fixed without a reinstall.

Comment: Min have disappear too! Very weird!

Comment: Mine have disappeared, too.  I guess I'll have to reinstall resharper.  <sigh>

Answer (score 19):

Reinstalling did not solve it for me.  This is from ReSharper's support.  Note: Run notepad as administrator.

http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/26859128-ReSharper-Fonts-Colors-settings-do-not-appear-in-Visual-Studio-after-installation

Problems:

- ReSharper Fonts & Colors settings do not appear in Visual Studio
  after installation;
- Colors from Light Color Theme are used with a
  Dark Color Theme;

Solution:

- Close all Visual Studio instances;
- Open C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {VS version}\Common7\IDE\Extensions\extensions.configurationchanged file;
- Type anything there;
- Save the file;
- Open VS and check Fonts and Colors in Tools | Options | Environment;

Answer (score 6):

To change the font colors of identifiers, goto:

> Resharper > options > code inspection > settting > checkbox

The color identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Colby! Re-Installing ReSharper took care of it.
For future reference, the complete scenario was:

I had a trial mode ReSharper installed, once the trial expired I purchased the license, I did not try to change the color scheme during the trial period, so I don't know if the options where there before.

After re-install I can go to Fonts and Colors and all the ReSharper options are there!