# How to change the font size of Resharper?

Tags: resharper

How to change the font size of the Resharper?

I found the font size of File Structure, Live Templates and other UI components unbearably small.

I couldn't find any options to customize font size. I tried to increase Windows DPI to 150%. That works but cause a lot of other problems.

I'm using Resharper 5.1.3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper still uses system font settings for many of its controls. Use the Control Panel to change font size in these controls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In Control Panel > Display > Appearance, I changed "Font size" to "Large", also in "Advanced Appearance" I changed all font sizes from "8" to "16". But unfortunately that didn't work. [A similar question](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/283240?tstart=0) was posted on Resharper's official forum almost 2 years ago, but hasn't got an answer yet.

Comment: Ah I think I have misunderstood your post. Do you mean changing the Windows DPI through the Control Panel? That works. But unfortunately causes a lot of other problems. Currently Resharper is the only program that forces me to set DPI to 150%.

Comment: The issue actively surfaced only recently (not surprisingly, as skinning is new to VS10). Hopefully, in ReSharper v.next all of the font settings will be derived from Visual Studio settings, but currently it's not an option for v6. Sorry.

Comment: FYI: most of R# 7.x UI supports theming for colors, font faces, and font sizes.

This immediately applies to all embedded VS UI (what's inside tabs and tool windows, and popups over them). UI in top-level windows, such as dialogs, has not been fully updated yet — though fonts should be OK in most places.

Answer (score 0):

Same as changing the colors, it's in visual studio options not resharper.
but under resharper settings.
Look at this link:

[Changing Resharper's color scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386953/changing-resharpers-color-scheme)

look carefully at the issues presented in some user's visual studio. I had to reinstall resharper in order to change the color and font size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Show settings for "Text Editor", I can only change Resharper's color scheme. I tried to change font size, but that only affects the font size in the Text Editor, not Resharper's UI components (File Structure, Live Templates...)

Comment: read the previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386953/changing-resharpers-color-scheme I had to reinstall resharper in order to change the environment fonts and colors. In that options (where you saw "Text Editor") must appear resharper controls.

Comment: I tried to reinstall Resharper 2 times on my main machine, but didn't work. To pinpoint the issue, I created a clean VMware virtual machine, installed XP SP3, Visual Studio 2010, and Resharper 5.1.3 in it. But unfortunately same issue. Here is a [screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1421509/forums/stackoverflow.com/resharper-3.png) I took from the virtual machine. Resharper's controls are not on the list :(